A question about Wu's parity check experiment
It is known that the Co-60 nucleus are polarized by an external magnetic field.
Is the magnetic field on when the data collecting starts? Or is it off?
I notice that the horizontal axis is time in her figure. As time elapses, the asymmetry dies out. It seems that the magnetic field is off, and the Co-60 nucleus depolarized by thermal motion.
Is my understanding right? If so, why is experiment done with the magnetic field off?


Can you give a link to the paper?

this is a fairly good description of the experiment with no ambiguities about the magnetic fields , they are always on. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_experiment#Experiment . one assumes  a certain number of excited cobalt within dt, and the time is the time axis where all have been deexcited

@mikestone  https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.105.1413
